# Fixed box over full screen carousel slide Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

based full screen carousel slide as the landing page of a `Rails 4 app`.

I am wondering, is it possible to add a fixed box (NOT a header) somewhere on the page (like a regular `div class="col-xs-4"`) and then have it be fixed as the carousel changes in the background?

> **i.e.** this box and its contents should not refresh with every slide, and should not slide off and then back on the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the carousel inside a position: relative container, then place an absolute positioned element inside of that, alongside the carousel.

```
<div style="position: relative;">

  // Carousel code here, positioned as desired.

  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"> // Style as required.
    contents of box
  </div>

</div>
```

You could post some code if you need people to provide a more context-specific example.